Unable to generate sentence embedding via multiprocessing
I am trying to generate sentence embeddings for say 300 sentences using a huggingface model and my code is just keeps getting stuck, execution just doesn't proceed.
I have put debug statements at different parts of the snippet but nothing conclusive.
On the contrary when i try to embed sentences sequentially, everything works smoothly.
Can someone suggest where is the issue ?
import torch
import multiprocessing as mp
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

def encode_sentence(sentence, model, tokenizer, output_list):
    encoded_input = tokenizer(sentence, return_tensors="pt")
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(**encoded_input)
    embedding = output.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]  
    output_list.append(embedding)

def worker(input_queue, output_list, model, tokenizer):
    while True:
        try:
            sentence = input_queue.get()
            if sentence is None:
                break  
            encode_sentence(sentence, model, tokenizer, output_list)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

    num_workers = mp.cpu_count()
    input_queue = mp.Queue()
    output_list = mp.Manager().list()
    workers = [mp.Process(target=worker, args=(input_queue, output_list, model, tokenizer)) for _ in range(num_workers)]
    for w in workers:
        w.start()

    sentences = ["This is sentence {}".format(i) for i in range(300)]
    for sentence in sentences:
        input_queue.put(sentence)

    for _ in range(num_workers):
        input_queue.put(None)  
    for w in workers:
        w.join()

    print(output_list) 


I have run your code and although the output means nothing to me, it runs to completion without any errors/exceptions

runs to completion, that is strange !! Do you mind pasting output (part of it) here in comments ?

The last 2 lines (of 45,901) are: 1.1115e-01, -8.7667e-02,  7.6376e-02,  8.8487e-04,  7.2613e-02,
1.0156e-02,  1.3487e-01,  4.7711e-01]])]

I see that code is running in VScode while in jupyter notebook it was stuck. sorry to bother you. I observed another issue which is that while I run this code, not all CPUs of VM are getting utilized, even though I am using multiprocessing. @SIGHUP Can you suggest something on this aspect?

Probably something to do with your VM set-up. On Apple Silicon M2 (8 CPUs) all CPUs are busy when this runs

Queues and managed lists are unnecessary for this. It just results in code bloat with no apparent benefits.
Using mp.Pool and map_async you could do it like this:
import torch
import multiprocessing as mp
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

MODEL_NAME = "distilbert-base-uncased"

def worker(sentence):
    global tokenizer, model
    encoded_input = tokenizer(sentence, return_tensors="pt")
    with torch.no_grad():
        return model(**encoded_input).last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]


def ipp(t, m):
    global tokenizer, model
    tokenizer = t
    model = m


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
    model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
    with mp.Pool(initializer=ipp, initargs=(tokenizer, model)) as pool:
        sentences = [f"This is sentence {i}" for i in range(300)]
        r = pool.map_async(worker, sentences)
        output = [e for e in r.get()]

    print(output)

Whether this will behave differently on your VM is impossible to tell

thanks for your snippet. @SIGHUP  Runs comfortable but Unfortunately, doesn't give speed up on my windows machine.

@prashantgpt91 That's because the model() function is relatively slow at ~0.075s and you're calling that 300 times albeit with some concurrency. On my machine, for 300 sentences, the total duration is just over 11s
